# sum with group in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I am new in **mongoid and mongodb**.
I have a model name `like_count(account_id, create_at, updated_at, like_cnt)`.
I need sum of the each accounts like count in a sorted order. 
I have tried something like

```
LikeCount.group_by(&:account_id).sum(:like_cnt)
```

But seems like it is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would be better off using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) method from MongoDB in the moped syntax. Other methods like `.group_by` are legacy JavaScript engine wrappers that are much slower at evaluating results:

```
LikeCount.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group" => {
        "_id" => "$account_id",
        "likes" => {"$sum" => "$like_count"}
    }},
    {"$sort" => { "likes" => -1}}
])
```

That uses the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage in order to aggregate results by the given `_id` key, and the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) pipeline orders the results, in this case in a "descending" order.

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) is implemented in native code and is much faster at processing results.

Comment: How can do I such an aggregation with a Mongoid criteria where several scopes have been selected already ? `MyClass.scope_1.scope_2....scope_n.your_aggregate` ?